# Sheets - If a tab within one of my sheets contains a name, return a string

Tags: google-sheets

So I have two tabs. Let's say both tabs have the name "John". I want to check through the column of names in one tab for the name "John". If the name is found, I want the cell to return "Found". If I couldn't find it in that column, it would return blank or "not found". What would be the most efficient way to do this if I want to do this for multiple names?

Answer (score 0):

> So I have two tabs. Let's say both tabs have the name "John"

within 1 spreadsheet you can't have two sheets/tabs with the same name

try IF:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; John!A1:A)); "Found"; "Not Found"))
```

Comment: If I wanted to check multiple would you use IFS? For example Tab A has John  and Suzy in a column full of names. Tab B has John in its name column and Tab C has Suzy in its name column. Idea is I won't know which tab they're in so I need to check both tabs. I do a run for John and if he comes out in Tab B, i'll return "Tab B". If I run through both tabs and Suzy appears in Tab C, it'll return "Tab C"

Comment: @Patrick you can put them in array like: {John!A1:A; Suzy!A1:A}